# glBlendFunc() with 32-bit RGBA textures

Tags: opengl, textures, alpha-transparency

I have a texture that is semi-transparent with varying opacity at different locations. I have the main texture bitmap, and a mask bitmap. When the program executes, the alpha values from the mask bitmap are loaded into the alpha values of the main texture bitmap. The areas that I want to be transparent have a value of 255 alpha, and the areas that I want to remain totally opaque have values of 0 alpha. There are in-between values also for mid-transparency.

I have tried all manner of glBlendFunc() settings, but it is either completely invisible or it acts on the RGB colors of the source texture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically in OpenGL, 0 means transparent and 255 opaque, which is the opposite that you have.

so something like:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Should work.

Comment: I just tried it. It is black everywhere that the texture is supposed to be transparent.

Comment: @old-school rules: are you sure something other than black was in the frame buffer when you did that draw? What's your clear color ? If black, try using something else, to see if it's a drawing order issue.

Comment: I will double check everything again... I have the background clearing to red to see how the transparency is working, but it's seriously jacked up right now.

Comment: The closest I can get is glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_SRC_COLOR), but that makes everything that isn't black transparent... the alpha values don't seem to have any affect there

Comment: @old-school rules: Is your texture color where it's transparent black ? I think you did not create your original texture correctly. What you describe sounds like the texture is seen as fully alpha=0.

Comment: yeah it would seem like it... i'm going to go through and try some different color schemes and check out the binary dump of the images

Comment: ok, so I changed the texture bitmap so that the mask is white in the areas where transparency is needed... in the texture, this area is also white... i'm going thru all of the glBlendFunc() settings and it's still acting the same... :| having VS freeze on me every few builds is really plucking my nerves

Comment: @old-school rules: You should not need to go through BlendFunc tests. I'm pretty sure the one I gave you should behave as you want, provided your texture data is correct. Check how exactly you generate the original texture map (when you combine your color and mask), that's where your issue likely is (share the code if you want).

Comment: when i use GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA it is totally invisible

Comment: there's so much of it, I don't think it would fit in this box... it's a renderer, calling an image library, calling opengl...

Comment: the code you provided provides a white background on the texture, no transparency... :| thanks for the help bud but I think I'm gonna be at this all day

Comment: @old-school rules: yes, alpha/1-alpha is standard GL transparency. Since your texture data is all alpha=0, everything becomes transparent. your texture data does not have the right alpha.

Comment: wow i'm an idiot... you were right... I just dumped it and the alpha value is still 0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was using `SDL_Image` to load my images. I realized when I was converting the image I was using `SDL_DisplayFormat` instead of `SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha`. This solved my issue.